# Let git use smaller granularity when merging

Tags: git

Suppose you want to merge two branches that change the same file. If the changes in that file are far apart of each other, no merge conflicts are to expect. Now say the changes from branch `A` are on line 500 and 502 and the changes from branch `B` are on line 501 and 503. It's likely that git will see this as a merge conflict.

It is possible to split hunks or to use smaller granularity when using `diff`, but: **Is it possible to use line-by-line, word-by-word or otherwise smaller granularity when merging?**

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to change how the conflicts are detected or just how they are presented?